# Only rescue specific OAuth2 errors

Tags: ruby, oauth

I'm using OAuth2 to make requests in the following format:

```
@access_token = get_access_token
begin
  @access_token.get(...).body
rescue OAuth::Error => e
   # handle errors
end
```

This works but it rescues ***all*** OAuth2 errors and I would like to only rescue specific errors.

For example if I only want to rescue Unauthorized errors. Is there something like `OAuth::Error::Unauthorized` or maybe response codes just using response codes `OAuth::Error::401`.

Is there any way to limit which `OAuth` errors that I rescue from?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know specifically whether or OAuth::Error has subclasses.

But here is a generally applicable way to rescue specific errors.

```
begin
  # raise error here
rescue OAuth::Error => e
  puts e.class # => OAuth::Error or some subclass
  if e.class == OAuth::Error::SomeSubclass
    # continue with rescue
  else
    raise e # the equivalent of "super" from a rescue block
            # i.e. act like the rescue didn't happen
  end
end
```

In addition to using `if` on `e.class`, you can get more information about the error with `e.message` and `e.backtrace`. Maybe something like `if e.message.include?("some string")`.

If you've determined that there is a subclass of the error, you can replace `rescue Oauth::Error` with only the subclass.